# I'm having trouble finding out if in hiragana if its like the English alphabet, and you just put letter together to make a word?

Tags: words

i need to find certain words in hiragana but i cant because people now mostly used katakana, so im wondering if to make a word (or find one) i have to learn what the letters mean to put them together to make up a word. (my word is exit but its not the point)

Comment: I'm confused by "people now mostly use katakana."

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, no, you cannot write out an English word using matching hiragana sounds and expect anyone or any search to understand what you are saying.

If you see a word written in katakana that *sounds* like an English word, it's because that is a defined loanword. Loanwords are always written in katakana.

If you need to know how to say 'exit' in Japanese, just use an English-Japanese dictionary like [Jisho](https://jisho.org/search/exit) or use a translator.